# How to increase left margin of ul list

Tags: list, margin

How to increase the space of the list (dots) in the left side
[image]

```
<div class="entry-content">
                        <div id="attachment_989" style="width: 160px" class="wp-caption alignleft"><a href="http://www.eldvigateli.com/blog/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8.html/lageri-predvaritelen-natyag-grab-grab" rel="attachment wp-att-989"><img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-989 " title="Лагери RHP T7014CTSULP3, прецизен клас на точност P2" alt="T7014CTSULP3 - RHP" src="http://www.eldvigateli.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lageri-predvaritelen-natyag-grab-grab-150x150.jpg" width="150" height="150"></a><p class="wp-caption-text">Лагери RHP T7014CTSULP3, прецизен клас на точност P2</p></div>
<p>Едно от критичните звена при електродвигателите са лагерите, голяма част от повредите в електромоторите са причинени именно от авария в лагерите. &nbsp;Основните причини са свързани с:</p>
<ul>
<li>Използване на евтини и некачествени лагери;</li>
<li>Неправилен монтаж и демонтаж на лагерите;</li>
<li>Неправилна експлоатация;</li>
<li><strong>Грешка при избора на заместващите лагери;</strong></li>
</ul>
<p>Докато при първите три случаи става въпрос по-скоро за небрежност и неопитен персонал, в последния вариант задачата е малко по-комплексна. Защото зависи както от дългогодишния опит на сервиза, който ще замени лагерите, така и от знанията на доставчика на лагери и контактите със световните производители.<span id="more-987"></span></p>
<p>Поради характера на българската икономика и&nbsp;факта, че някои лагери се използват изключително рядко, доставчиците на лагери в България не поддържат наличности от всички типове лагери.&nbsp;Това може да наложи срок на доставка от 2 и повече седмици. Повечето фирми не могат да си позволят Спиране на електродвигателите и съответно производството за толкова дълъг период от време и тогава започват проблемите…</p>
<p>Друг проблем е, че много марки производители на лагери вече не съществуват, а международните стандарти за лагерите, както и фирмените номенклатури са изменяни многократно през годините. Това затруднява точното определяне на вида на лагера и води до грешки.</p>
<p>На последно място, но не по важност трябва да се имат предвид специфичните особености при монтажа на някои типове лагери – лагери с ъглов контакт, двуредови ролкови лагери, четириточкови лагери, керамични лагери, електрически изолирани лагери,&nbsp;лагери работещи в чифт DF,DB, с особености като – предварителен натяг, обработка на контактните повърхнини DF, DB и много други.</p>
<p>Ако имате дори и малки съмнения при смяна на лагерите, обърнете се към Елин Инженеринг ООД.</p>
                                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use margin-left in your CSS.

```
ul {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_margin-left

Answer (score 0):

If you mean move the dots to the right, you need to use the margin-left property like this:

```
ul { margin-left: 15px; }
```

You may also want to set other values such as ul {padding: 0px;} for a more consistent look on different web browsers.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But the dots start moving right after 300+px, not 15px :(

Comment: With just the HTML you've provided, what I get looks completely different and you don't have your text to the right of the image but below it so I'm not seeing an issue. Also you only asked how to increase the left margin of the dots in general. If you've got a specific issue with your page, why not post the entire page and CSS so people can see your problem? e.g. Use JS Bin.